# append input box using jQuery

Tags: jquery, input, append

Hi friends trying to add an input box by clicking on button and also applying `onfocus` and `onblur` functions on newly created input box for you reff plz see this link **http://jsfiddle.net/2TDZA/** and also check my code mentioned below. The main problem is when i add an input the script which will be use while `onfocus` and `onblur` are stop working please help me guys

Thanks in advance.. :)

**HTML**

```
<table width="278" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="emailTable">
        <tr>
          <td width="207" align="left"><input name="" value="Enter Friend’s mobile no" type="text" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter Friend’s mobile no') {this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value ='Enter Friend’s mobile no'}" placeholder="Enter Friend’s mobile no" autocomplete="off"/></td>
          <td width="71" align="right" valign="top"><div class="addRow">Add</div></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
 $('.addRow').click(function () {
        $('#emailTable').append("<tr><td  align='right'><input name='' value=\"Enter Friend’s mobile no\" type='text' onfocus='if(this.value == \"Enter Friend’s mobile no\") {this.value= ''}' onblur='if(this.value == ''){this.value =\"Enter Friend’s mobile no\"}' placeholder=\"Enter Friend’s mobile no\" autocomplete='off'/></td><td class='delRow'> X</td></tr>")
        })

 $(document).on("click", '.delRow', function (event) {
        $(this).parent('tr').remove();
    });
```

Comment: after input added onblur and onfocus stops working on newly added input

Comment: Looks like blur and focus are not set for dynamically created elements. See aruns answer below and modify the blur and focus events.

Comment: Not it's not like that. It can be set. Here the problem was simply quotes...

Comment: @FurquanKhan no the problem was also delegating event using `on`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the code below:

```
 $('.addRow').click(function () {
    $('#emailTable').append("<tr><td  align='right'><input name='' value=\"Enter Friend’s mobile no\" type='text' onfocus='if(this.value == \"Enter Friend’s mobile no\") {this.value= \"\"}' onblur='if(this.value == \"\"){this.value =\"Enter Friend’s mobile no\"}' placeholder=\"Enter Friend’s mobile no\" autocomplete='off'/></td><td class='delRow'> X</td></tr>")
    })

$(document).on("click", '.delRow', function (event) {
    $(this).parent('tr').remove();
});
```

Or refer to the updated fiddle:

[Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/2TDZA/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery event handlers instead

```
 $('.addRow').click(function () {
     $('#emailTable').append("<tr><td  align='right'><input name='' value=\"Enter Friend’s mobile no\" type='text' placeholder=\"Enter Friend’s mobile no\" autocomplete='off'/></td><td class='delRow'> X</td></tr>")
 })

 $(document).on("click", '.delRow', function (event) {
     $(this).parent('tr').remove();
 });
 $('#emailTable').on("blur", 'input', function (event) {
     if (this.value == '') {
         this.value = "Enter Friend’s mobile no";
     }
 });

 $('#emailTable').on("focus", 'input', function (event) {
     if (this.value == 'Enter Friend’s mobile no') {
         this.value = "";
     }
 });
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gtwSL/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $('.addRow').click(function () {
    $('#emailTable').append("<tr><td  align='right'><input name='' value=\"Enter Friend’s mobile no\" type='text' onfocus='if(this.value == \"Enter Friend’s mobile no\") {this.value= \"\"}' onblur='if(this.value == \"\"){this.value =\"Enter Friend’s mobile no\"}' placeholder=\"Enter Friend’s mobile no\" autocomplete='off'/></td><td class='delRow'> X</td></tr>")
    });
```

I have removed single quotes and added double quotes in your code.